# Yaml file has not being recognized in application.context

Tags: spring, yaml

I´m trying to use yaml instead of properties and in every application context i have, i put the application.yml

```
<!-- Enable the configuration for utilization of @PropertySource & @Value
    annotations -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:Messages.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:application.yml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However the application doesn´t recognize the file:"Cannot resolve file 'application.yml" and the properties in @Value are not being translated.

I put mannualy the application.yaml in every resource folder but doesn´t work,
what i need to do?

Thanks

Comment: you're writing that you put `application.yaml` in the resource folder but you specified `application.yml` in the config (note the missing `a` of `yaml` vs `yml`)

Comment: The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` works only with property files.